# PHP Error with Login Form

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

I did not create a database for this login form to post to yet... I am getting an error saying syntax error, unexpected '<' on line 118. This code is supposed to check for invalid characters and display an error message if the invalid characters listed are found. I apologize for the code not being in the correct format for this post.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
function checkCharacters($input_string)
{
    $char_array = str_split($input_string);
    $string_length = strlen($input_string);


    for($i = 0; $i < $string_length; $i++)
    {
       if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 39)    //ASCII value of ' is 39
          return false;

       if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 34)    //ASCII value of '' is 34
          return false;

       if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 59)    //ASCII value of ; is 59
          return false;

       if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 60)    //ASCII value of < is 60
          return false;

       if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 62)    //ASCII value of > is 62
          return false;

       if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 35)    //ASCII value of # is 35
          return false;

       if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 37)    //ASCII value of % is 37
          return false;

       if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 36)    //ASCII value of $ is 36
          return false;

       if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 38)    //ASCII value of % is 38
          return false;

      if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 43)    //ASCII value of + is 43
          return false;

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 58)    //ASCII value of : is 58
          return false;

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 40)    //ASCII value of ( is 40
          return false;  

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 41)    //ASCII value of ) is 41
          return false;  

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 42)    //ASCII value of * is 42
          return false;  

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 33)    //ASCII value of ! is 33
          return false;  

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 45)    //ASCII value of - is 45
          return false;  

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 47)    //ASCII value of / is 47
          return false;

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 60)    //ASCII value of < is 60
          return false;

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 61)    //ASCII value of = is 61
          return false;

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 62)    //ASCII value of > is 62
          return false;

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 63)    //ASCII value of ? is 63
          return false;  

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 91)    //ASCII value of [ is 91
          return false;  

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 92)    //ASCII value of \ is 92
          return false;  

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 58)    //ASCII value of : is 58
          return false;

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 93)    //ASCII value of ending bracket is 93
          return false;  

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 94)    //ASCII value of ^ is 94
          return false;  

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 95)    //ASCII value of _ is 95
          return false;  

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 96)    //ASCII value of ` is 96
          return false;  

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 123)    //ASCII value of { is 58
          return false;  

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 124)    //ASCII value of | is 124
          return false;  

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 125)    //ASCII value of } is 125
          return false;

        if(ord($char_array[$i]) == 126)    //ASCII value of ~ is 126
          return false;  

    } //end for

    return true;

} //end checkCharacters function
<form id="login" action="login.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<fieldset >
<legend>Welcome to Scrabble! Login below. </legend>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="1"/>

<label for="username" >UserName*:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"  maxlength="10" />

<label for="password" >Password*:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="10" minlength="8"/>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
</fieldset>

$name = $POST['Name'];
$name_valid = checkCharacters($name);

$password = $_POST['Password'];
$password_valid = checkCharacters($password);

if(($name_valid == false) || ($password_valid == false))
        echo "You have entered an invalid username/password combination. Please try again.<br /><br />";
</html>
?>
```

Comment: you need to close (`?>`) your php before outputting HTML, then open (`<?php`) it again when going back into PHP.

Comment: You need to separate your PHP code from your HTML with `<?php` and `?>` tags. Your `<form>` tag is currently being parsed as PHP

Comment: you are missing a PHP closing tag (`?>`) just before this line: `<form id="login" action="login.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: Please read the docs for [in_array](http://php.net/in_array) (or use `>=` and/or `<=` operators) and then re-write this.

Comment: on a different note - it would be beneficial to read something about [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), as your code could get really huge by using the presented approach...

Comment: At best if you don't want to break up your structure, you have two options as previously stated in comments here, or you can echo your form code like this 

`echo "<form id='login' action='login.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>";` and so on, following the same syntax. You have to put PHP with PHP, and HTML with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

These rows must be isolated as they are not valid PHP. You need a closing PHP tag before and an opening PHP tag after.

```
<form id="login" action="login.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<fieldset >
<legend>Welcome to Scrabble! Login below. </legend>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="1"/>

<label for="username" >UserName*:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"  maxlength="10" />

<label for="password" >Password*:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="10" minlength="8"/>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
</fieldset>
```

This is valid for you:

```
?>
<form id="login" action="login.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<fieldset >
<legend>Welcome to Scrabble! Login below. </legend>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="1"/>

<label for="username" >UserName*:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"  maxlength="10" />

<label for="password" >Password*:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="10" minlength="8"/>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
</fieldset>
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

...or use heredoc syntax

```
<?php

if($a == $b){

echo <<<_HTML

<div id="foo">Hello World</div>

_HTML; // <-- Important! no whitespace before or after ending heredoc syntax


}

?>
```